# End session with Flurry Analytics in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, analytics, flurry

I have an iOS application that is using the Flurry Analytics SDK. This application is being used as a kiosk in a museum setting with it running in Guided Access mode. I need to be able to start and end new sessions without exiting the application. In the documentation it states that the SDK will send the data and start a new session on close and when the application is paused. Since this application is never exited or paused (backgrounded) I do not get any analytics data without having to exit guided access mode and exiting the app.

I have inquired about this with the Flurry team and do not have a response yet so thought it would be worth checking to see if anyone has had a similar issue.

Comment: [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com)? They have checkpoints...

Comment: did you receive an answer from the flurry guys by now?

Comment: No, I never did get a response. We have since switched to Google Analytics for apps (for better or worse)

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score -3):

Not tested but could it be as simple as using

```
[FlurryAPI endSession];
```

and then recalling

```
[FlurryAPI startSession:"API KEY HERE"];
```

UPDATE: endSession is no longer available as of v6.0.0

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, there is no public method of endSession

Comment: not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but it looks like the best way of doing it could be start a timed event and then call [Flurry endTimedEvent:@"EVENT_NAME" withParameters:YOUR_NSDictionary]; every time